# python SyntaxError when trying to import package BUT only when running remotely

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I have the following scripts:

1. test.py:

   ```
   import sys
   try:
       import random
       print random.random()
   except:
       print sys.exc_info()[0]
   ```
2. run.sh:

   ```
   python "test.py" >> "test_file" ;
   ```

when running the following command on my linux server:

```
[saray@compute-0-15 ~]$  nohup ./run.sh  &
```

test_file includes a random number as expected:

```
[saray@compute-0-15 ~]$  cat test_file
0.923051769631
```

BUT, when running the same command remotely using:

```
[saray@blob-cs ~]$ ssh "compute-0-15" 'nohup ./run.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
```

python fails to upload random package!!

```
[saray@compute-0-15 ~]$ cat test_file
exceptions.SyntaxError
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your remote machine is running a different Python version, Python 3.

In Python 3, the `print` statement has been replaced with a `print` *function*, and your code is throwing a syntax error.

The work-around is to either run the code remotely with Python 2 as well, or to make your code compatible with both Python 2 and 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

import random
print(random.random())
```

Comment: But merely calling `python` should still start Python2. If we want Python3, it should be addressed as `python3`. Or did that change recently?

Comment: @glglgl: depends on the distribution. Arch and Gentoo use `python` for Python 3. Bad, BAD distros!

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Many distros are in the process of converting to Python3 as their default version. For example it is expected that Ubuntu 13.10 will have Python3 as default. if you are in a heterogeneous environment it is far safer to explicitly specify the version of Python that you want>

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, and that is why distros that use `/usr/bin/python` for  Python 3 are a pain to have to deal with; Debian, Ubuntu and RedHat / CentOS / Fedora all use `python3` instead.